# Calculate UICollectionViewCell height base don UITextView attributed text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` which has a `UITextView` as its subview, anchored to the cell's bounds.

What I'm trying to achieve here, is based on the `UITextView attributedString` , calculate the height the `UITextView` should have, to not to be scrollable and apply that size to the cell's height.

The problem here is that the `NSAttributedString` may have different font size in it and it also may have some images, which will increase its size.

How can I calculate the size, based on that content , which can have multiple inner forms (sizes, line breaks, images) ?

I use to apply the following function, but it does not work in this case, because the inner content, like font size may defer, it isn't constant:

```
private func estimatedHeightForText(_ text: String) -> CGFloat {
    let approximateWidthOfBioTextView = view.frame.width - 24 // paddings
    let size = CGSize(width: approximateWidthOfBioTextView, height: 1000) // height of 1000 is an arbitrary value
    let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)] // attributes of the text

    // gets the estimation height based on Text
    let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
    return estimatedFrame.height
}
```

Any hint?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following could be the code for a simple ViewController.

[image]

Where I am just loading the some dummy content in the **UITextView**.
After which the delegate of the `UITextView` in the `UITableViewCell` is set to this `ViewController`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView:UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellId = "textCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId)!

        return cell

    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }




}
```

There are 3 key points to achieve the auto resizing in the simple way.

1) For UITextView "Srolling Enabled" set it to "**NO**" .

2) Setting the UITableView Dimensions to Automatic and set some estimated height (I am using Xcode 9 , but you can set with **UITableView** property)
[image]

You can also check the autolayout resizing attributes attached below.

[image]

3) Now when you edit the textView you can have delegate update the UITableView or reload the particular indexPath in **beginUpdates** and **endUpdates** . `func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)`